# FInalBuilder 7 and TFS2010 - Get Latest

Tags: finalbuilder

Can anyone shed some light please on the process of getting FB7 linked to TFS2010 so that I can pull source code from TFS into a FB build routine?

I am getting the following message in the build log when I go to execute a TFS "Get" Action:

```
Path to Executable: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe
Workspace Directory: W:\
Command line: get /login:"<domain>\<username>",*PASSWORD* . /all /overwrite /recursive /noprompt
Error: Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'.
Failed!
```

The configuration features for TFS seems to be extensive in FB7 (in comparison to FB6, which has nothing), but appallingly liberal with ability to enter free-text.

Documentation for how to link TFS to FB7 seems to be pretty thin on the ground also, so we are just about in guesswork mode.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT 20140319: here are the TFS workspaces available:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>tf workspaces
Collection: http://tfs1:8080/tfs/app%20systems
Workspace    Owner               Computer     Comment
------------ ------------------- ------------ --------------------------------------
APPBUILD2    <domain>\<username> APPBUILD2
```

Comment: Bernard would you be able to list the workspace mappings setup on the build process.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>tf workspaces
Collection: http://tfs1:8080/tfs/app%20systems
Workspace    Owner          Computer     Comment
------------ -------------- ------------ --------------------------------------
APPBUILD2    ABC\TFSservice APPBUILD2

Comment: Jason, yes, I have edited the original post - hopefully this is what you mean?

Comment: Ahh yes. Vincent is correct you will need to map the workspace to a local directory first. Apologies I thought you were using the TFS Workflow model not just running a FinalBuilder script to get the latest from a repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Map Working Folder Action if you are trying to get to a folder that isn't mapped to a workspace. This is just how TFS works, you can't just checkout anywhere, you first need to map the working folder.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Turned out that I was also using FB7 with the wrong user profile.