# Three identical build server, same build script: "Unable to determine workspace" error only on one

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, continuous-integration

We implemented three identical build servers and when we run the same script it fails on one of them with the following error:

> Error: Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'.

The issue is identical to this one, so we probably need to add the `tf workfold /map` command:

[FInalBuilder 7 and TFS2010 - Get Latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470103/finalbuilder-7-and-tfs2010-get-latest)

Now the question is, if we need to add the command above, how it can run correctly many times on the other two build servers?

```
[Team Foundation Check Out [ C:\BuildAgent\work\27a5ec307fc309bf\Core\Geometry\Source ]]
             Path to Executable: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TeamExplorer\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe
             Workspace Directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\27a5ec307fc309bf\Core\Geometry\Source
             Command line: checkout /lock:none "Properties\assemblyInfo.cs"
             Error: Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'.
             Failed!
```

Comment: What is the script...?

Comment: Added the incriminated script portion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a ghost workspace, I was able to delete it using `Attrice Sidekick for TFS` and the instructions found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37284964/261010